# setExposureModeCustom crahes in iPhone X swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, iphone-x

I have an app, which will access Camera's Exposure mode settings for changing the Shutter Speed of the Camera with Custom values. And it's works as expected in maximum devices, except iPhone X. Below is the code which i am using,

```
do {
    try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    captureDevice.setExposureModeCustom(duration: CMTimeMake(1,30), iso: 120, completionHandler: { (time) in
})
    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}
```

It's crashes in above line and crash log says to check whether `isExposureModeSupported`.

[image: crash log screenshot].

What is my problem is, we can check `isExposureModeSupported`, but if is all the iPhone X device doesn't support Custom Exposure mode? if so how can we make to support Custom Exposure Mode in iPhone X?

Or Do we need to change anything in the Camera Settings?

Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: have you checked `isExposureModeSupported(.custom)` ?

Comment: @LalKrishna I need to check, but i don't have a iPhone X with me right now. So it will be helpful for me to know,  if `isExposureModeSupported(.custom)` returns `false` what can we do?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue where setExposureModeCustom crashes on iPhoneX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPhone x does support custom exposure, but when the `builtInDualCamera` device is selected all the custom settings are disabled. You just need to use another device, `builtInWideAngleCamera` or `builtInTelephotoCamera`.